# Issues using .startswith() for a specific location in a string

Tags: python, data-science

I have a text file, which has many lines of data in it. I need to check each line of this text file and process the data contained within the line accordingly (i.e. save to a separate, tabulated .txt for analysis)

The text file is in the following format:

- Number 1 or 0 (denoting relevance of data)
- An ID for each line (referring to what the data is)
- The data itself (contained in rest of line)

So this is what two example lines may look like:

1 ID:K-95 *list of data*

0 ID:D-56 *list of other data*

Such that the first line had relevant data to ID K-95 and the second had irrelevant data to ID D-56.

I want to parse the text file, and sort the data contained within each line based on the relevance (0 or 1) and the data ID. I.e. save each line with the same ID in order of relevance (first all the lines with 1 and then with 0). Lines can have the same ID, but different data. Lines are also always of a fixed length.

To do this I came up with:

```
idtag = input('Enter ID:')

with open("example.txt", 'r') as f:                                                                                         
    for line in f.readlines():                                                                                              
        if line.startswith('1') and line.startswith(idtag, 5, 3):                                                                                            
            print line
```

Having trouble with this however. Specifically around the second condition after the and operator. I can print/select lines based on whether there is a 0 or 1, no problem. However, using the `.startswith()` method with a defined position seems to return nothing: no error, no printing - it simply executes and returns nothing.

Any ideas? Maybe a better way of parsing this data to meet my objective?

Comment: is the list of data separated by a delimiter, say comma?

Comment: @SaikatKumarDey Yes, it's separated by spaces in the following format: a:100F b:150A c:41S

Comment: Are the number of items in the list fixed ?

Comment: @SaikatKumarDey Yes they are, there is a fixed number for each entry. As stated 'Lines are also always of a fixed length.'

Answer (score 3):

The `start` and `end` are interpreted as absolute positions (specifically: `end` is not interpreted relative to `start`) for [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

> `str.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return `True` if string starts with the *prefix*, otherwise return `False`. *prefix* can also be a tuple of prefixes to look for. With optional *start*, test string beginning at that position. **With optional *end*, stop comparing string at that position.**

So instead of

```
line.startswith(idtag, 5, 3)
```

you need to use

```
line.startswith(idtag, 5, 5+4)
```

The two parameters are equivalent to slicing notation:

```
line[5: 5+4].startswith(idtag)
```

For example:

```
>>> a = 'abcdefg'
>>> a.startswith('c', 2, 1)
False
>>> a[2:1]
''

>>> a.startswith('c', 2)
True
>>> a[2:]
'cdefg'

>>> a.startswith('c', 2, 3)
True
>>> a[2:3]
'c'
```

Comment: If the example IDs given are representative, you'll also need to increase the end parameter (line[5:5+3] would give you "K-9" which would not match "K-95").

Comment: OK, so the 3 in the line:
`if line.startswith('1') and line.startswith(idtag, 5, 3):`
was a typo, I was supposed to put 4 because I thought it pertained to length of substring, rather than relative position.

However, I'm still having the same issue...
`if line.startswith('1') and line.startswith(idtag, 5, 5+4):                                                                                            
            print line`
The print statement in this code block does not execute, the line is not returned

Comment: @tyrfingnir I did test it in a slightly different way and it worked: https://gist.github.com/MSeifert04/5c35af67aea9bd64df0bbe79d6104301 - I don't know what you entered for `idtag` and how your file looks like - so maybe there is just no match?

Answer (score 1):

I realise there's already an answer, but as an alternative you could also just check if idtag exists in the line:

```
idtag = input('Enter ID:')

with open("example.txt", 'r') as f:                                                                                         
    for line in f.readlines():                                                                                              
        if line.startswith('1') and idtag in line:                                                                                            
            print line
```